# Is client id and consumer key the same in oauth/API gateway?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

I am exploring the world of oauth and APIs. Then I bumped into a question.
I am wondering: is client id the same as consumer key? What about API key?
Some web site says they are the same, some web sites says they do not. I cannot find an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

> No. Client ID/Client Secret is different from Consumer ID/Private Key combination. Consumer ID/Private Key was required for the old authentication method. With oAuth you will have to use only the ClientID/Client Secret that you can get from Developer Center.

https://developer.walmart.com/faq/us/faq-auth/

So, the answer is that the two are different. Consumer ID was required for the old authentication method and with OAuth you will only need ClientID / Client Secret